# Why do designated initializers work in C++?

Tags: c++

After having searched the web for a bit I've come to the conclusion that designated initializers are not part of any C++ standard, yet when compiling this code using g++ (4.7.0)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int test[2][2] ={
        [0]={1,2},
        [1]={3,4},
    };

    for (int x = 0; x<2;x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y<2; y++)
        {
            cout << test[x][y] << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

it will compile and run fine.

Am I missing something ? From everything I have read C++ should not support this type of code.

Comment: You're correct--this isn't allowed in C++. For better or worse, g++ includes a number of C99/C11 features as extensions, even when compiling C++.

Comment: This is rather puzzling, [GCC's documentation seems to say that this is *not* supported in C++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html). Not sure what I'm missing, since the code looks like it certainly can't accidentally be compiled as C.

Comment: It definitely compiles with gcc 4.8.0 w/o warnings, even with `-pedantic -ansi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each compiler usually has its own language extensions. It is valid as for g++ and as for example MS VC++.  For example in MS VC++ you can use statement for each.

Comment: Alright, so does that mean that g++ is adding more features to C++ that are technically not part of the standard ?

Comment: Yes, it means so. For example you can use variable length arrays that are not allowed in the C++ Standard.

Comment: @PJMicolet It certainly does, as do most other compilers. This is called *extending* the language. You can [see this list of g++'s extensions to C++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html).

Answer (score -1):

It seems you found a *feature* of the gcc compiler: an undocumented extension that cannot be suppressed or be warned about by using any options (such as `-pedantic -std=XXXX`).

If you want to be reasonably certain that your code complies with the standard, I recommend to always use a variety of compilers and make sure your code passes all of them without warnings (and use the most strict warning options). gcc and clang are free, so you can always use at least two compilers (and clang is quite good at standard compliance).